# osm2pgrouting command not found

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I have installed osm2pgrouting on my Ubuntu 12.04 server with the following code from this [tutorial](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:georepublic/pgrouting-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install osm2pgrouting
```

Which ran happily. Unfortunately however, when I go to use osm2pgrouting at the command line, the tool is missing. I realise I could follow the [instructions](http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html) on github but I was hoping to get an easy `sudo apt-get install` working out of the box.

Thus, how can I get this tool working at the command line? I suspect it is something to do with paths...

Comment: what does `locate osm2pgrouting` print?

Comment: Same problem here... apt-get does not work..
> locate osm2pgrouting doesn't print anything (where is the file???)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be here: `/usr/share/bin/osm2pgrouting`

See also:
https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

But particularly if you are dealing with large data (e.g. europe.osm) you might want to try [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/) instead of osm2pgrouting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got this working (on Linux Mint, which has worked for everything I've done on Ubuntu)

Dependencies for building the install:

Install cmake

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Install boost

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Install expat

```
sudo apt-get install expat libexpat1-dev
```

Install libpqf (if necessary)

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Once you've got that going, the "installation" found on the [osm2pgrouting github page](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting) work just fine:

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild
cd build/
make
make install
```

To run the tool, it seems you have to be in the directory mentioned in the other answer, which you can get to with:

```
cd /usr/share/bin
```

Now the command on the github page is different than the command on the official [PGRouting Page](http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html), which combined with the github code, is based on this command:

```
./osm2pgrouting -file your-OSM-XML-File.osm -conf mapconfig.xml -dbname routing -user postgres -clean
```

My command looked like:

```
./osm2pgrouting -file ~/Documents/pgrouting/osm2pgrouting-master/denver-boulder_colorado.osm -conf ~/Documents/pgrouting/osm2pgrouting-master/mapconfig.xml -host localhost -dbname postgres -user matthew -clean
```

Notice I also had to specify the path to the mapconfig.xml file...

So when the command is run and all is said and done the message you should get look something like this:

```
Create Topology success
#########################
size of streets: 154076
size of splitted ways : 379396
finished
```

Now on to some routing!